# Map function returning a empty value list

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to map my firebase data and add it to a usestate hook in order for it to have a list of data. But I am getting empty list. I have used display hook to store objects
example of one object

```
type:"others"
dayNumber:348
sum:130
id:"QDstSFIDgn72vrcsqcrP"

it has a list of these objects. Here is my code.
function BarChart(){
  const moneyCollectionRef = collection(db,"dailyData")
  const [display,setDisplay] = useState([]);
  let a ={
    labels:display.map(d=> ( d.dayNumber)),
    datasets:[{
      label:"Daily Expense",
      data: display.map(d=> ( d.sum)),
    }],
  }
  const [userData,setUserData] = useState({
    labels: [],
    datasets:[{
      label:"",
      data: [],
    }],
  });
  setUserData(a);
  
  useEffect(()=>{
    getUsers()

  },[]);

  const getUsers = async () =>{
    const data = await getDocs(moneyCollectionRef);
    setDisplay(data.docs.map((d)=>(
      {
      ...d.data(),id:d.id
    })));
  };

  // console.log(display)
  return <Bar data={userData} />;

}

export default BarChart;
```

I am getting a empty list. Kindly help. how can I get a full list with all daynumbers from display hook.

Comment: Where exactly you getting empty list? the `map` by itself in your case works totally fine

Comment: the map function is working fine when I am performing it standalone. the userData.labels is returned empty even after performing the map operation.

Comment: So it is not about map, could you share more code ?

Comment: Is `data.docs` an empty array?

Comment: @konrad its not, when I am executing it in normal object like {a} above, it shows values. I checked that many times.

Comment: I am following this tutorial, its working fine for him, https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=RF57yDglDfE&ab_channel=PedroTech. I dont know why my object is not accepting the values